# How to add bitbucket private repository in gradle with bitbucket api v2.0

Tags: java, gradle, bitbucket-api

My gradle project is down because it has some dependencies on bitbucket repo and the bitbucket v1 api was deprecated.

I've googled a lot about how to migrate to v2 but doesn't find a good solution.

The v1 api in gradle is like this:

```
repositories {
  maven {
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
        url "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/<Team>/<repo>/raw/<branch>"
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid comment, but did you try simply changing `1.0` to `2.0` in the url?

Comment: @MarcusHeld yes, I already tried man. Now it works perfectly with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
repositories {
  maven {
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
        url "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<Team>/<repo>/src/<branch>"
  }
}
```

According to v2 API reference, I updated the url, and with `curl -u username:password https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<Team>/<repo>/src/<branch>/<path>` I can get raw data, but gradle still not works and always  Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

After specify `basic` authentication explicitly, gradle works as expected

```
repositories {
  maven {
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
        url "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<Team>/<repo>/src/<branch>"
  }
}
```

Below is gradle documentation 
`If no authentication schemes have been assigned to this repository, a default set of authentication schemes are used based on the repository's transport scheme.`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, my credentials is correct without any problem. I have worked it out and please see my updated answer.

Comment: Can you run the job with `-d` for debug output and verify that the correct credentials are being used?

Comment: I have updated the answer, the question is about how gradle use the credentials, I don't know why it works for bitbucket api v1, but for v2 API, we might have to specify `basic` auth explicitly

Comment: im not sure why but the only way I could get it working is to use my bitbucket credentials (email & password) in place of the maven user credentials. Based on your answer aren't I suppose to use maven user & password? @ahunigel

Comment: How can you add the implementation in build.gradle after youve added the reopsitory credentials and info? My lib is in maven java.

Comment: What is `mavenUser` and `mavenPassword` here? @ahunigel